# Making a Multi-Line chart in Vega-lite frommultiple ES queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite

I'm new to using vega-lite/vega and am attempting to make a Kibana visualisation in vega-lite-v4 to display data that originates from multiple indices on my elastic search. I'm having trouble defining the data. When I set the schema to just vega the data set can be found in the vega debug screen however in vega-lite this appears to be invalid use of defining data.

All I'm looking for is a way to properly define the data property. The mark, encoding etc. is not relevant to me but is included just so it meets basic schema criteria.

When using this code I get the following messages in yellow on the viz, since the data is never properly defined anyway.

Infinite extent for field "key": [Infinity, -Infinity]
Infinite extent for field "doc_count": [Infinity, -Infinity]

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json
  title: A vega-lite viz
  data: [
    {
      name: dataset_1
      url: {
        index: index_1
        body: {
          aggs: {
            histogram_1: {
              date_histogram: {
                field: @timestamp
                calendar_interval: 1w
                extended_bounds: {
                  min: now-150d
                }
                min_doc_count: 0
              }
            }
          }
          size: 0
        }
      }
      format: {
        property: aggregations.histogram_1.buckets
      }
    }
    {
      name: dataset_2
      url: {
        index: index_2
        body: {
          aggs: {
            histogram_2: {
              date_histogram: {
                field: @timestamp
                calendar_interval: 1w
                extended_bounds: {
                  min: now-150d
                }
                min_doc_count: 0
              }
            }
          }
          size: 0
        }
      }
      format: {
        property: aggregations.histogram_2.buckets
      }
    }
    {
      name: dataset_3
      url: {
        index: index_3
        body: {
          aggs: {
            histogram_3: {
              date_histogram: {
                field: @timestamp
                calendar_interval: 1w
                extended_bounds: {
                  min: now-150d
                }
                min_doc_count: 0
              }
            }
          }
          size: 0
        }
      }
      format: {
        property: aggregations.histogram_3.buckets
      }
    }
  ]
  mark: {
    type: line
  }
  encoding: {
    x: {
      field: key
      type: temporal
    }
    y: {
      field: doc_count
      type: quantitative
    }
  }
}
```